# PsExec treats second remote computer in list as a program name

Tags: powershell, psexec, sysinternals

PsExec behaves very strangely when run on a specific server

When I use PsExec to run a program on multiple remote machines in most cases, it works perfectly fine.  When I run the same command on one specific machine, it treats the second server provided in the comma-separated list like it's a program name.

Here's my call to the remote servers:

```
psexec \\server11111,server11112 /accepteula -u "Domain\User" -p "password" -i 2 -d cmd.exe /c "wmic bios getsmbiosbiosversion"
```

And here's the output:

```
PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

PsExec could not start server11112 on server11111:
The system cannot find the file specified
```

This command works fine when I run it on my dev machine.  However, when I run the same command from a server running Windows 2012, it fails and I get the output above.

Comment: The name of the computer might be the key, it might have a special character which might need to be escaped.

Comment: @davidbaumann the names will always be like "harvest99999".  They'll only have the server type and number with no special characters.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator I am not.  The [PsExec spec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) shows that you only have to put the backslashes once for a comma-separated computer list.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator Done.  The description should be functionally equivalent to what I'm doing now.

Comment: Much better. This command works for me **if** I remove the backslash preceding `psexec` (is that just a formatting mistake)?. Does session #2 actually exist on both target machines?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator Yes, the backslash was a formatting mistake.  And yes, session 2 is guaranteed to exist.  This command works for me when run on my dev machine, but running on a server running Windows Server 2012, that's when it fails and gives the output outlined above.

Comment: powershell:  gwmi win32_bios -Property SMBiosBiosVersion -computername server11111,server11112

Comment: Does it work if run from Command Prompt? What version of PS is on the 2012 box?

Comment: Does it work if run from Command Prompt? What version of PS is on the 2012 box?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator I just checked and it does work with command prompt.  Also, playing around with it I discovered that if I surround the server list in quotes it will also work.  Ex: "\\server11111,server11112"

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator and it's powershell major version 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on [Patrick](https://superuser.com/users/972852/patrick)'s [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1383399/911683), instead of listing servers with the `\\computer[,computer2[,...]` format, you can use a list of computers from a text file.

From the `psexec` documentation (through `psexec /?`):

```
Usage: psexec [\\computer[,computer2[,...] | @file]][-u user [-p psswd][-n s][-r servicename][-h][-l][-s|-e][-x][-i [session]][-c [-f|-v]][-w directory][-d][-<priority>][-a n,n,...] cmd [arguments]

     @file      PsExec will execute the command on each of the computers listed
                in the file.
```

That is, you can create a text file (for example `computers.txt`) in the directory you're working from filled with computer names:

```
computer
computer2
computer3
```

Then you can use the command:

```
psexec @computers.txt /accepteula -u "Domain\User" -p "password" -i 2 -d cmd.exe /c "wmic bios getsmbiosbiosversion"
```

`psexec` will then run the command on each computer in order as specificed in `computers.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

Call a list not from the commandline:

```
psexec @ListOfServers /accepteula -u "Domain\User" -p "password" -i 2 -d cmd.exe /c "wmic bios getsmbiosbiosversion"
```

Comment: This answer could be much improved by explaining how the list of servers works.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you have a non-displaying character after the comma. I get the exact same

> PsExec could not start <server2> on <server1>:

error if I have a space after the comma.

Comment: Do you know what characters could be non-displaying in powershell?  It is acting as if there were a space there, because putting double quotes around the entire server list fixes it for some reason.

Comment: In other contexts, the Zero-Width Space and Left-To-Right Mark are the ones that have tripped me up. You can try saving the string to a file and opening it with a hex editor, like [Frhed](http://frhed.sourceforge.net/en/) to see what character might be hiding in there.